# No static file is cached

Tags: nginx, cache, cloudflare, cdn

I have set up CloudFlare for my website http://www.funfun.org.cn, the caching level is `Standard` and The development mode is `Disabled`.

By loading the home page http://www.funfun.org.cn/1/#/home, I can see `Server: cloudflare` in the response header. But it seems that all the static JS files have `CF-Cache-Status:MISS` in their response header.

Does anyone know why?

**Edit 1:** I also see `Cache-Control:no-cache` in the request header. How could we modify this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you say, is likely the "no cache" directive. Have a look at [my tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/#ccheaders) which goes through setting up Nginx and CloudFlare.

The key parts for you are using Nginx to set caching headers. You'll need Nginx to have the "[headers more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module)" module included - "nginx -V" will tell you if it was compiled in. Some distributions include this, otherwise you'll have to [build Nginx yourself](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source), which is pretty straightforward (if you Google it there will be many many articles, including the Nginx website).

The following clears the existing headers

```
more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Expires";
```

Then we can set the header manually. For image we use quite a long expires time

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
```

For pages we keep it shorter – many sites will need this much shorter or even set to no caching

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";
```